Can Collibra Data Quality be used to monitor the data in motion which is part of a data pipeline?
Collibra Data Quality can be used to monitor the data quality of datasets within data lakes and data warehouses. However, can it be used for real time monitoring of data quality as the data flows within data pipelines e.g. ETL jobs. Can Collibra Data Quality provide real time feedback on the data quality even before it has been ingested into the data lake or the data warehouse.
I am trying to figure this feature out so that I can prevent poor data from landing into the Data Lake and Data Warehouse.
